# Meaning of "on the page" in "When you were around, he was on the page."

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What kind of condition is "on the page" in the following paragraph?

> He was confined to the house, and that was horrible. He would sit in a chair with a book and just sit there. There was nothing left for him. The only time I saw him happy was when you visited. When you were around, he was **on the page**. He adored you: you were Daddy’s little girl. Otherwise, it was take a nap, take a nap, there was nothing else left. He liked to eat, and that was it.

This is in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=4g2oAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=%22When+you+were+around,+he+was+on+the+page.%22&source=bl&ots=Ay2kZnPOCr&sig=2i2uLwVwBcl9bLoBTruYAUeJ-UA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0yZ6diJTKAhUGGpQKHR5fC1kQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22When%20you%20were%20around%2C%20he%20was%20on%20the%20page.%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

When a character in a story or a novel is "on the page", this means he is mentioned in that part of the book: he is doing something - loving, hating, communicating etc.

When a character is "off the page", this means the narrative is taking its course without him/her. Some other characters are mentioned, but this particular character is not mentioned.

So then Daddy was "on the page", this means he suddenly turned into an active person, playing his part in life, instead of being a listless person, "part of the backdrop". It's a nice literary metaphor.

---

Example of usage:

> Dear Readers, Chris Chapey appeared in each of my Men Who Walk the Edge of Honor books, and any time he was **on the page**, he stole the show. ([Google Books](https://books.google.ru/books?id=0SQaNz-tc0UC&lpg=PT3&dq=%22he%20was%20on%20the%20page%22&hl=ru&pg=PT3#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20on%20the%20page%22&f=false))

---

P.S.

The phrase "on the page" adopts different meanings depending on context. It could used be to refer not to a hero's presence in some particular part of a book, but to his presence in a literary work generally.

It could also be used to compare the impression a writer leaves in real life to the impression he delivers through his writing.

> He was as funny **in person** as he was **on the page**.

So it's kind of versatile phrase.

Comment: What dialect is this common in? I'm northeastern American and I've never heard of "on the page" being used as it is in that book. It seems more metaphorical than the example usage you cited, since the father isn't actually in a play. I'm fairly certain I would have no idea what is meant by that phrase except from context clues if it weren't explicitly explained to me.

Comment: @Paul - of course it's more metaphorical, since her father is was a real person, not a fictional character. I explained the meaning of the phrase in the context, then provided an example of it used in a more literary sense.

Comment: @Paul - I don't beleive this particular use is common. I believe the author strove exactly to come up with an originally-sounding expression, instead of using a common idiom in a standard way.